# Which matrix represents the similarity between words when using SVD?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, math

Two words can be similar if they co-occur "a lot" together. They can also be similar if they have similar vectors. This similarity can be captured using cosine similarity. Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix counting how often $w_i$ occurs with $w_k$ for $i,k = 1, \dots, n$. Since computing the cosine similarity between $w_i$ and $w_k$ might be expensive, we approximate $A$ using truncated SVD with $k$ components as: $$A \approx W_k \Sigma W^{T}_{k} = CD$$

where $$C = W_{k} \Sigma \\ D = W^{T}_{k}$$

Where are the cosine similarities between the words $w_i$ and $w_k$ captured? In the $C$ matrix or the $D$ matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some material [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html#truncated-singular-value-decomposition-and-latent-semantic-analysis) and [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.4061.pdf) but the idea (at least in this case) is the following: consider the full SVD decomposition of the symmetric matrix $A = W \Delta W^T$. We want to calculate the cosine similarity between the $i$-th column (aka word) $a_i$ and the $j$-th column $a_j$ of $A$. Then $a_k = A e_k$, where $e_k$ is the $k$-th vector of the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}$. Let's call $\cos(a_i,a_j)$ the cosine between $a_i,a_j$. Then
$$\cos(a_i,a_j) = \cos(Ae_i,Ae_j) = \cos(W \Delta W^T e_i,W \Delta W^T e_j) = \cos(\Delta W^T e_i,\Delta W^T e_j)$$

where the last equality holds because $W$ is an orthogonal matrix (and so $W$ is [conformal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map), i.e. it preserves angles). So you can calculate the cosine similarity between the columns of $\Delta W^T$. A $k$-truncated SVD gives a well-enough approximation. In [general](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/134282/82135), columns of $W \Delta$ and rows of $W$ have different meanings!

Comment: But isn't $W^T$ also orthogonal and therefore conformal? If yes, why can't we simply use the diagonal matrix?

Comment: Also $W^T$ is orthogonal and conformal, but you only "simplify" on the left: if $f$ is a conformal map, $g$ any function, then $\cos(f \circ g(x),f \circ g(y)) = \cos(g(x),g(y))$, but in general $\cos(g \circ f(x),g \circ f(y)) \neq \cos(g(x),g(y))$

Comment: @nbro for example, consider [this matrix](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=svd+%7B(1,0,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,1)%7D): $\cos(Me_1,Me_3) = 1 = \cos(\Sigma V^T e_1, \Sigma V^T e_3)$ but $\cos(\Sigma e_1,\Sigma e_3) = 0$ (cosine between different columns in a diagonal matrix is always $0$).